# Getting past the Tree of Life in "Seasons"

Tags: seasons

In one of the early missions in [Seasons](http://www.jorisdormans.nl/seasons/about.html), you're instructed to stand next to the Tree of Life and throw energy at it (or, at yourself, a la how the orange energy works while in the cave to light your way.)  It didn't seem to matter where I stood or where I threw the energy (myself or the tree), the tree never responded, and the game never moved on.  Is there a trick I'm missing?

Comment: Please don't re-add the platform tags; they're not relevant to answering your question.

Comment: @Frank oh, sorry. :)